# How to visualize and validate public transportation data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, routing

I am building a routing solution app for my city using public transit. Currently I have data regarding bus stops and routes.

Currently its an sqlite table with one table containig busstops with their latitude and longitude, and other containing all the bus routes, linking bus stops and having the bus time table.

How should I go about visualising the data using qgis?  I need to visualise the data to validate my data set and to extract more information to develop my routing solution.

Comment: Check out building your data into the GTFS: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, please ask only one question per question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
What format is your transit data in?

Comment: @raphael my data is in sqlite table.  I have bus stops table and their latitude and longitude. As well as a routes table connecting the bus stops, as well as having timings.

Comment: @DPSSpatial I looked into GTFS and needed help regarding conversion from non standard formats to GTFS. I have posted my question here, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214964/how-to-convert-my-data-to-gtfs . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check out the linking layer tutorials

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: As links can break or videos be removed, please provide a small description of the process so that future users can use this answer even if the links breaks.