# Converting data to GTFS?

Tags: software-recommendations, transportation, general-transit-feed-specification

I currently have the transit data of my city in sqlite, following are the tables

(STOP TABLE)
STOPID STOP LATITUDE LONGITUDE

(ROUTE TABLE)
ROUTEID STOPID

(ROUTE SRC_DEST)
ROUTEID SRC DEST

(TIME TABLE)
ROUTEID STARTTIME ENDTIME ISUP

Are there tools to help converting non-standard formats to GTFS?

Comment: Take a look at the list of libraries here: https://github.com/luqmaan/awesome-transit , one of them might help you get started. Otherwise, if you can post your data, you never know who might help, we're a friendly bunch ;)

Comment: post about this on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/transit-developers , you can reach out to more static GTFS folks there

Answer (score 1):

Safe Software's FME Version 2016 can read sqlite (among numerous other formats) and write GTFS etc. http://www.safe.com/ 
You are welcome to evaluate FME and make use of our support to see if this solution is suitable.